# How to convert an array index to/from a mask

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an array like:

```
a1 = np.array([.1, .2, 23., 4.3, 3.2, .1, .05, .2, .3, 4.2, 7.6])
```

And I filter out, and create a mask, of all values less than 1, like:

```
a2 = a1[a1 >= 1]
a2_mask = np.ma.masked_where(a1 < 1, a1)
```

And then search for a specific value:

```
a2_idx = np.where(a2==3.2)[0][0]
```

How would I convert that index to the corresponding index in the original array?

e.g.

```
>>> a2_idx
2
>>> a1_idx = reframe_index(a2_idx, a2_mask)
>>> a1_idx
4
```

My naive implementation would be:

```
def reframe_index(old_idx, mask):
    cnt = 0
    ref = 0
    for v in mask:
        if not isinstance(v, (int, float)):
            cnt += 1
        else:
            if ref == old_idx:
                return ref + cnt
            ref += 1
```

Does Numpy have a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

`a2` is a copy, so there's no link between it an `a1` - except for some values.

```
In [19]: a2
Out[19]: array([23. ,  4.3,  3.2,  4.2,  7.6])
In [20]: np.nonzero(a2 == 3.2)
Out[20]: (array([2]),)
In [21]: a2[2]
Out[21]: 3.2
```

The `mask` of `a2_mask`, just `a1<1`, does give us a way of finding the corresponding element of `a1`:

```
In [22]: a2_mask = np.ma.masked_where(a1 < 1, a1)
In [23]: a2_mask
Out[23]: 
masked_array(data=[--, --, 23.0, 4.3, 3.2, --, --, --, --, 4.2, 7.6],
             mask=[ True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,
                    True, False, False],
       fill_value=1e+20)
In [24]: a2_mask.compressed()
Out[24]: array([23. ,  4.3,  3.2,  4.2,  7.6])
In [25]: a2_mask.mask
Out[25]: 
array([ True,  True, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,
       False, False])
In [26]: np.nonzero(~a2_mask.mask)
Out[26]: (array([ 2,  3,  4,  9, 10]),)
In [27]: np.nonzero(~a2_mask.mask)[0][2]
Out[27]: 4
In [28]: a1[4]
Out[28]: 3.2
```

So you need the mask or indices used to select `a2` in the first place.  `a2` itself does not have the information.

```
In [30]: np.nonzero(a1>=1)
Out[30]: (array([ 2,  3,  4,  9, 10]),)
In [31]: np.nonzero(a1 >= 1)[0][2]
Out[31]: 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem recently, so I made [`haggis.npy_util.unmasked_index`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.npy_util.unmasked_index)<sup>1</sup>. This function has a lot of overkill for your relatively simple case, because it's intended to operate on an arbitrary number of dimensions. That being said, given

```
>>> arr = np.array([.1, .2, 23., 4.3, 3.2, .1, .05, .2, .3, 4.2, 7.6])
```

and

```
>>> mask = arr >= 1
>>> mask
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
       True,  True])
```

You can do something like

```
>>> idx = unmasked_index(np.flatnonzero(arr[mask] == 3.2), mask)
>>> idx
array([4])
```

If you ever need  it, there is also an inverse function [`haggis.npy_util.masked_index`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#haggis.npy_util.masked_index) that converts a location in a multidimensional input array into its index in the masked array.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Disclaimer: I am the author of haggis.</sup>